# How to enable php5-mysql in ubuntu 16.04 trough cli?

Tags: drivers, php, docker

I want to enable the module php5-mysql in my Ubuntu 16.04 trough the cli.

When I do `apt search php`, I see `php5-mysql is there`.
Then run `apt-get install php5-mysql` and that is what I get :

```
root@25814ad2fc62:/var/www/html# apt-get install php5-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

So the conclusion is that this module is installed but not enabled.
Following that [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66127/is-there-any-command-to-enable-disable-a-php-extension-from-command-line), I see run the command php5enmod mysql and have no messages or errors.

After run `php -m` I see that mysql is not there:

```
root@25814ad2fc62:/etc/php5/mods-available# php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

And these are available modules in my machine:

```
root@25814ad2fc62:/etc/php5/mods-available# ls
mysql.ini  mysqli.ini  opcache.ini  pdo.ini  pdo_mysql.ini  redis.ini
```

So, how can I enable this mysql module in this instance of my php?
I am running inside a docker container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini
```

And make sure it contains an uncommented line like this:

```
; configuration for php mysql module
; priority=20
extension=mysql.so
```

Lines starting with `;` are comments and are ignored.

Restart `apache` or `nginx` or `php-fpm` after this change.